# Why is such function continuous?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Can anyone help me see why the function $f: \bar{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{Q} $ where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ denotes the set of algebraic numbers,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\ \text{if the real part of $x$ is greater than $\pi$, and}\\
0,&\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

is continuous?

Comment: **Hint :** If $\mathrm{Re}(z)=\pi$, then $z$ is not algebraic.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thank you! So basically I don't have a discontinuity at $\pi$ ...

Comment: I guess what one needs to show here is that $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{z\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > \pi \}$ is both open and closed in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Comment: @b.omega Yes, if you want take any point $z \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, and a sequence $(z_n)$ that converges to $z$. Then either $\mathrm{Re}(z) > \pi$, and then $\mathrm{Re}(z_n) > \pi$ from a certain rank, so $f(z_n)=f(z)=1$ from this rank and you are done ; either $\mathrm{Re}(z) < \pi$, and then $\mathrm{Re}(z_n) < \pi$ from a certain rank, so $f(z_n)=f(z)=0$ from this rank and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $z \in \mathbb C$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $Re(z), Im(z)$ are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. Now, to show that $f$ is continuous we need only show that $f^{-1}[0]$ and $f^{-1}[1]$ are closed. Indeed, $f^{-1}[1]$ is precisely those $z \in \overline{\mathbb Q}$ such that $Re(z) > \pi$. Since $Re(z)$ is algebraic and $\pi$ is transcendental, $Re(z) > \pi$ iff $Re(z) \geq \pi$. Now, let $S \subseteq \mathbb C$ be defined as $\{z \in \mathbb C : Re(z) \geq \pi\}$. The map $Re: \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is just projection, so it is continuous. Thus, $S = Re^{-1}[[\pi, \infty)]$ is closed. Furthermore, as discussed, $S \cap \overline{\mathbb Q} = f^{-1}[1]$. Then as $S$ is closed in $\mathbb C$, $S \cap \overline{\mathbb Q} = f^{-1}[1]$ is closed in the subspace topology.

$f^{-1}[0]$ consists of $Re(z) \leq \pi$ so essentially the same argument shows $f^{-1}[0]$ is closed. Hence, $f$ is continuous.